# Error installing framework7 to cordova with Npm

Tags: node.js, npm, html-framework-7

I'm trying to install framework7 on ubuntu 18.04.
The node version is: v10.24.1
and the Npm is: 6.14.12

the erro:

```
npm ERR! Linux 4.15.0-154-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "i" "framework7-cli" "cordova" "-g"
npm ERR! node v8.10.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.5.2
npm ERR! code EMISSINGARG
```

I also get a warning:

```
WARN engine cordova@10.0.0: wanted: {"node":">=10.0.0"} (current: {"node":"8.10.0","npm":"3.5.2"})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you have globally installed Cordova (may require "sudo"):
`$ npm install -g cordova`

Then install framework7-cli (may require "sudo"):

`$ npm install -g framework7-cli`

To create Framework7 app, run the following command in the directory where you want to create app:

`$ framework7 create`

Please take a look at the Framework7 guide [here](https://framework7.io/docs/), or [here](https://github.com/framework7io/framework7-cli).
You can ask questions to the community directly [here](https://forum.framework7.io/):